# How to compute the following probability involving two normal random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian

$\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ are two independent standard normal random variables. What's the conditional probability $$\mathbb{P}[\alpha >0, \alpha' >0|c_1<|\alpha - \alpha'|<c_2],$$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two positive constants.

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such type questions. Hint: integrate the density of the binormal distribution with zero correlation over the annular sector.

Comment: I don't see a closed form answer arriving; you would need to be able to find the indefinite integral of $e^{-(x-a)^2}\,{\rm erf}(x)$ , which I don't think has a closed form expression.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Numerically for concrete values of $c_1,\,c_2$.